# File open and apostrophes in file names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some simple code [CentOS 7 & python 3.6, because... stuck with a VM image]:

```py
with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
    # do stuff
```

Which is grand & wonderful - does the self-closing thing, and has no problems with spaces in filenames.

Except it can't cope with filenames with apostrophes:

> Error reading Why Doesn't this Code Work?!.py: near "t": syntax error

I tried a sneaky

```py
with open(f"{filename}", "r") as read_file:
    # do stuff
```

And that made no difference, and even a desperate

```py
with open(f'"{filename}"', "r") as read_file:
    # do stuff
```

Which is just totally broken (whichever way you do the quotes)

Is there a way to do this.... noting I'm realistically stuck with python 3.6

Comment: Could you write more details on what you are doing. E.g. also where you define `filename` (so we can test). Also the error: could you write it exactly (and the stack). Syntax errors seems to come from a different line: you have no `'` in the code you wrote.

Comment: That is not a Python error message. Python syntax errors don't look like that.

Comment: How do you define `filename`? Please provide the exact name

Comment: For those asking: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchRoot):` then `filename = f"{root}/{file}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the error by escaping the apostrophe with a back slash. Modified code:

```py
filename = filename.replace("'","\'")

with open(filename, "r") as read_file:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: When didn't I think of this.... it's obvious!

Sadly, it's not working for my case.... which makes me wonder if the character is a unicode character, rather that ASCII #27 :scowl:

Comment: It's weird that this is accepted; there's something completely unrelated going on which isn't obvious from the question if this actually worked.